# TCL: regexp exclude strings having characters

Tags: tcl

I am not much skilled in TCL or using TCL regexp. But I am in need of a TCL mechanism / regexp which can exclude or let know that a word has some special characters if given a line / sentence.

Assume that I have a line/sentence something like below:

```
 (space)(space)At 4:00:00AM (not sure) please do your work ...
```

Now I try to split the line to get each words to loop using foreach:

```
% set fields [split "   At 4:00:00AM (not sure) please do your work" " " ]
{} {} {} At 4:00:00AM (not sure) please do your work
```

But again I do not want empty fields:

```
% foreach val $fields {
       puts $val
}



At
4:00:00AM
(not
sure)
please
do
your
work
```

Further to that I would like to exclude words in foreach loop that have special characters like:

```
(not
sure)
4:00:00AM
```

exclude words having '(' or ':' in start , end or anywhere in the word.

Please let me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Tcl regexp does not support look-behind operators. Otherwise it could be achieved with a single regexp.
But, you can use the following code to construct the list of words you needed:

```
set the_line "   At 4:00:00AM (not sure) please do your work"
set fields {}
foreach {- val} [regexp -all -inline -- {(?:^|\s)([^:()\s]+(?=\s|$))} $the_line] {
    lappend fields $val
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set str "   At 4:00:00AM (not sure) please do your work"

# split the string into space-delimited words
set words [regexp -inline -all {\S+} $str]

# eliminate words containing a character other than letters, numbers, underscore
set alnum_words [lsearch -inline -regexp -all -not $words {\W}]
```

`alnum_words` now contains the list `{At please do your work}`

If you only want words made up of only letters, use

```
lsearch -inline -regexp -all $words {^[[:alpha:]]+$}
```